# Calculated column: Lookup

Tags: list, custom-list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Say I have a Date/Time [Date] column and a numerical [Value] column. I am creating a calculated column. I need a formula that will find the row with the most recent date in the [Date] column, then return the data in its [Value] column. Is this possible in SharePoint 2007?

EDIT: My requirements (sorry for the long read)

I have 8 KPI measures that are updated monthly. Currently I'm storing these in a list, with the 8 measures as 8 columns. I also have a date column and a month column that is calculated from that date column. I need to display the latest record from this list in a KPI list (where I will set the boundaries for the indicator colours, etc.)

What I thought would solve it would be creating a 'Latest' view of the list that has the values for the measures for each month, and then limiting the number of entries returned to 1 item and sorting by date. This does indeed display only the latest record.

However, when I create an 'Indicator using data in SharePoint list', set the view to this new 'Latest' view, and go 'Calculation using all list items in the view' -> Sum, it sums over all the items, instead of the ones in the 'Latest' view.

Is my only option likely to be using custom code, or can my current method be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No a calculated column can only look at the data in the current row, it can not retrieve information from other rows to produce the result you are mentioning.

You will need to achieve this result through custom code. This can be either server side or client side code with javascript to set the values of a text field based on this calculation.

Comment: Thank you. Is it also not possible to create a list view that shows only the row with the most recent date in the [Date] column? edit: I think I have it, I just need to limit the number of items returned. This should solve my problem.

Comment: Yes you can do exactly that, create a list view sorted by date and only return 1 item. If you want a less interactive page (list view will still have filtering options and ribbon commands) you could use a content query web part to query the list and only return a single item, and for that item to be the most recent.

Comment: If you are having any difficulty, you can post your requirements here and we can help you with various ideas on how to deliver this

Comment: I think some of what you currently have in your solution is a bit unclear to me. My understanding is that you have a list of items and you only want to base your indicator values on the latest one. You are then creating an indicator list (which you referred to as a KPI list, just making sure we are on the same page) to display the indicator based on the various fields in the latest item

Comment: If my understanding from above is accurate, then I don't think you will get the result you are looking for using an indicator list. The indicator list is meant for calculating based on all list items, or showing an indicator based on the maxiumum or minimum value of a particular field, but this will not take into account other fields

Comment: If you were using SharePoint 2010 or 2013 you would have a lot more options. Conditional formatting in 2010 and JSLink in 2013 would achieve this easily for you. I think because you are using 2007 I think your two best options would be to use javascript to render the 1 item view to show your desired indicators, or you could use a content query web part and create a custom ItemLink Style to render traffic lights rather than show the actual values of the item. Hopefully that explanation made sense

Comment: Ah no, sorry, I will re-explain. I have a list (List 1) of data. Each row in List 1 has 8 fields, which are values for 8 different indicators. I want to take the 'latest' row from List 1. I have a separate KPI list (List 2). I want to add 8 indicators/items to List 2, one for each field in my 'latest' row. One field in my 'Latest' record (which came from List 1) will correspond to a value for a single indicator in List 2.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think I may have identified your issue. I have replicated your setup and the behaviour you described seemed to be related to how you set up the "1 item view". In the item limit section, you need to make sure you tick the box titled "limit the total amount of items returned". If you have the "display items in batches" option ticked, then the KPI list will still work from all items. Try ticking that box and seeing if this helps

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the issue persists - very strange.

Comment: Ok, I solved it using workflows. What you suggested is definitely the more robust and logical though. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Great glad you sorted it. Just to add I replicated the issue and I agree there is something wrong. When the KPI list says use items in this view, even if there is only one item in the view, it bases its calculation on all items. This is really strange and I am not sure why this is happening.